# Diferentes pasaje (o paso) de parámetros

Tags: paso-por-referencia, paso-por-valor

Tengo dudas con los pasajes (o pasos, es lo mismo) de parámetros en las funciones. Por ejemplo, más abajo voy a copiar un `pseudo-código` (no es ningún lenguaje en particular) y querría saber la diferencia entre los distintos pasajes de parámetros. O sea, qué valores toma este ejemplo en cada uno de esos pasajes(pasos):

> 1) Por valor (call-by-value)
>
> 2) Por referencia (call-by-reference)
>
> 3) Por valor-resultado
>
> 4) Por nombre (call-by-name)
>
> 5) Por necesidad (call-by-necessity)

```
int i, A[2]
i <- 1
Procedure foo (int x, int y)
  int temp
  temp <- x
  x <- y
  i <- 0
  y <- temp
end

A[0] <- 0
A[1] <- 2
foo (i, A[i])
print i, A[0], A[1]
```